# Cannot register domain: Parameter value policy error (Unsupported language)

Tags: dns

I am trying to register a domain that contains the character à.

I am using AWS Route 53 to register this domain, but i am getting this error:

> We weren't able to register the domain name. This is because:
>
> 2306 : Parameter value policy error (Unsupported language)

I have tried to change the language to something other than english, for example italian, since italian has that accent, but still i am not able to register it. It goes without saying that the domain is flagged as available.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By contacting the support i have found out that the .band registry, Donuts, does not support Italian as an IDN. I used Arabic instead and it worked just fine.